# Confusion with C# declaration

Tags: c#, vb.net

what does this declaration mean :

```
int ? value
```

and what is he's equivalent on VB.NET .

Thanks

Comment: Cut the OP some slack - have you tried googling on "int?" - certainly nothing related on the first page of results.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Searching for "C# int?" gives plenty of good results. Searching for "C# specification" and then searching the specification would also have worked.

Comment: You're right, "C# int?" does do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It means that this integer is nullable, you can assign a null value to it... try to do that with an integer without a ? and it with throw an exception

Edit:
Oh and VB.net will declare a nullable int like this

```
    Dim i As Integer?
```

Comment: Uh, I'm pretty sure that's invalid syntax for a nullable `int`.

Comment: Could be, it's been a while since I used vb.net, one moment I'll try it out on LinqPad

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It runs ok in LinqPad, and I can assign Nothing to it, although the Nullable(Of Integer) seems to be the more used syntax

Comment: Alright friend, +1 for you!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Woohoo, that puts me over 1000, you're my hero!

Comment: I remember the feeling. I remember then after that it was when I broke 10K.

Comment: VB supports the ? syntax for Nullable types.  See section 7.1.1 of the VB Spec.

Answer (score 2):

`int?` is short for `Nullable<int>`. The VB.NET equivalent is `Nullable(Of Integer)`.

Comment: VB.Net also supports the ? notation for nullable types. (VB 10) – Chris Dunaway

Answer (score 2):

It's declaring a new instance of the `Nullable<Int32>` type. `int?` is just a shorter way of writing it.

**Further Reading**

- [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It is a `Nullable<int>` data type.

The equivalent in vb is `Dim value as Nullable(Of Integer)` or `Dim value as Integer?`

Answer (score 2):

It's syntatic sugar for

```
Nullable<int> value
```

meaning that it can have a null value

Answer (score 1):

Nullable value types. It means that the variable can contain a null value. For more details both for VB.NET and C#.NET view this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It a nullable int and is a short term of

```
Nullable<int> value;
```

In VB.net you would write

```
dim value as Nullable( of Integer )
```

See this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) for more details and examples.

Comment: VB.Net also supports the ? notation for nullable types. (VB 10)

Answer (score 1):

Try to read about nullable on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The question mark refers to nullable type in C#.  You can try using Nullable (Of Integer) in VB.NET.